# How do I reshape a numpy array for use with scipy interpolate?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

I have 3 numpy arrays with long, lat and rain values:

```
[-7.4989786799999996, -7.5215012000000003, -7.4764561599999997, -7.4989786799999996, -7.5215012000000003, -7.4764561599999997]

[41.90415308, 41.90415308, 41.90415308, 41.881630559999998, 41.881630559999998, 41.881630559999998]

[0.020928397800000002, 0.0299166963, 0.0171956848, 0.0340920761, 0.0429551788, 0.0301877651]
```

Scipy interpolate requires 1 array with 3 distinct Lons, another one with 2 distinct lons and a 3x2 array of rain values. How can I reshape them?

Comment: try reshape http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html

Comment: My problem is that I have to consider 3 diferent connected arrays.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you're wanting a 2D interpolation.

For example, let's use some random data similar to yours and plot it:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
np.random.seed(1) # Make example exactly reproducable

num_points = 20
lon = 0.1 * np.random.random(num_points) - 7.5
lat = 0.1 * np.random.random(num_points) + 41.8
z = 0.05 * np.random.random(num_points)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
artist = ax.scatter(lon, lat, c=z, s=200, cmap='gist_earth')
fig.colorbar(artist)
ax.axis('tight')
plt.show()
```

[image]

For this case, a good choice of interpolation algorithm would be a Radial Basis Function of some sort (e.g. a spline).  In scipy, that's `scipy.interpolate.Rbf`:

```
import scipy.interpolate

interp = scipy.interpolate.Rbf(lon, lat, z, function='linear')

# 20x20 grid of points to interpolate on
yy, xx = np.mgrid[lat.min():lat.max():20j, lon.min():lon.max():20j]

zi = interp(xx, yy)

# Plot the results
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
artist = ax.scatter(lon, lat, c=z, s=100, cmap='gist_earth',
                     vmin=zi.min(), vmax=zi.max())
ax.pcolormesh(xx, yy, zi, cmap='gist_earth')
ax.axis('tight')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Very clear (and carefull) explanation. Nevertheless, my question was around array reshape. I made some efforts meanwahile.

Comment: @Hugo - Which interpolation function are you using? You won't need to reshape your arrays for most of them.

Comment: I am using RectBivariateSpline

Comment: @Hugo - RectBivariateSpline won't work for your case.  It's for interpolating data that's already on a regular grid.  You're presumably dealing with "scattered" input data.

Comment: No. I am dealing with "rectangular" mesh, not "quadrangular" mesh. Distance between latitude and longitude is diferent.

Comment: @Hugo - If you're worried about that, `RectBivariateSpline` won't help you. Use a projected coordinate system instead of lat,long.  If you really need to get fancy, you can use spherical harmonics. Don't do that unless you know what they are and know you need them, though.  In general, projections exist for a reason.  It's best to interpolate in a projected coordinate system for exactly the reason you mentioned.  However, from the `scipy` side, it's identical.  Now that I look at it, though, your input points are on a regular grid. In that case you can use `RectSphereBivariateSpline`.

Comment: I am getting a `LinAlgError: singular matrix`. This is suposed to be a matrix inversion error. May I have repeated lon or lat values?